# why do UITableViewCell bounds can't be redefined before clipping to the cell bounds?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have some problem, and I Hope some seasoned iOS developer would show up and help.

I have a `UITableViewCell` that can slide with a touch recognizer

[image]

I need to have clipsToBounds activated (because I have the cell contracting and expanding vertically), anyway, I use this and it's preventing the content to exceed to the other cells when contracting

```
self.clipsToBounds = true;
```

but there is a tiny problem

now when i swipe, the green button don't show up

[image]

so I update my custom cell to have the bounds changed like this before applying clipping to the cell bounds like in the code below

```
self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.y,
    self.bounds.size.width + 50,
    self.bounds.size.height)

self.clipsToBounds = true;
```

My main question is : why clipping to bounds ignores my new definition of the bounds of the cell?

that `self.bounds` definition get's ignore, why?

Thanks a lot.